# Does python shelve module allocate space in chunks of a certain size?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shelve

I stored some pandas dataframes in a shelve and then stored the same dataframes but potentially containing a bit more data (maybe a few % more). The second shelve is about twice the size of the first one.

Does the `shelve` module pre-allocate space in chunks by any chance? My first shelve is ~ 100MB the second one is ~ 200MB. The increase in the size of the shelves does not correspond to the increase in the size of the underlying data. Could it be that `shelve` can only allocate in multiples of 100MB? So if I need 90MB it will allocate 100MB and if I need 110MB, it will allocate 200MB?

Comment: No, it doesn't pre-allocate space. The reason you don't see a linear relationship between underlying array size and storage space is most likely just due to the serialization method -- which is `pickle`ing your objects.  The [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/shelve.py) for shelve is pretty small and it's pretty plain to see there's no pre-allocation.

Comment: Do you mean that it is selecting a different serialization method in the two cases? Or that the serialization method is the same but it decides to allocate the extra space on disk?